# Replace a power adapter 12V/1A DC with 15V/0.8A

Tags: power, dc, battery-charging, adapter, watts

I have a [battery-charger](https://i1.adis.ws/i/maplin/N98EJ_1?w=265&h=265&qlt=80&img404=N98EJ_set&v=1&locale=en-gb) that has an input of `12V/1A` as specified in the [specs](https://www.urbanoutback.com.au/assets/images/Nitecore%20D2%2016b.JPG).

Can I replace the adapter with a `15V/0.8A` adapter ? I also have a `9V/0.85A`

Will both work ? Which is more suitable and safer to replace with, or should I buy a `12V/1A` ?

I was told `15V/0.8A` and `12V/1A` are practically the save since the have the same Power result in watts of `12W = 12*1 = 15*0.8` ? Is this correct ?

Comment: You are not telling us what you intend to power with the adapter

Comment: @A.J. It's a battery charger, simple 2 NiMH batteries slots.

Comment: *I was told 15V/0.8A and 12V/1A are practically the save* Don't listen to whoever gave you that advise, they clearly know little about electronics. A device that needs 12 V **might** be damaged at 15 V. It depends on the device how long it can handle 15 V. So since 15 V and 12 V are **not** the same, buy a new 12 V adapter. Without knowing the **complete design** it is impossible to guarantee that 15 V will be OK.